# Why Closure Compiler and YUI Compressor have different annotation format?

Tags: yui, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I tried to google for it, but couldn't find anything on why Google Closure Compiler and YUI Compressor using different annotations format

Google Closure Compiler is using JSDoc format in which annotations starts with `/**`
Any annotations in different format are removed.

YUI Compressor only keep annotation if they are started with `/*!`

I've noticed that most libraries(e.g. jQuery) using `/*!`

Could you tell me why most libraries use `/*!` and not JSDoc(which I guess quite popular?) format?

I couldn't find any flags for Google Closure Compiler to keep annotations starting with `/*!`

What's the best way to parse files with annotations in both formats with Google Closure Compiler and keep all the annotations? Shell script which using stream editor to replace `/*!` with `/**` and back again after minification?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I cannot understand what your question really is. If it's "why", then that's just like asking why you have both Eclipse and Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Closure Compiler removes all comments except those part of @license or @preserve in JSDoc annotations (which it moves to the head of the file).  "/*!" serves a similar purpose.

More specifically, no one has care enough to about "/*!" to do the work add support to Closure Compiler. It should be reasonable to do so as both YUI and Closure Compiler use Rhino's javascript parser (I'm not sure what version YUI uses but Closure Compiler uses the current one).

Comment: So what format for annotations would you suggest?
YUI removes annotation even if they have `@license`.